# DocuSign Java API - tabs

Tags: java, docusignapi

I saw there is an option to preview the envelop and do changes before sending it for signing.

Because I want to upload new and different documents each time I want to have a clean envelope without any 'tabs' for signature in it. And during the preview mode, set the signature fields and only after that send the document for signing.

Wanted to know if its possible to do with Java Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a senderView like as explained in [Sender View](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/), same call is available with JAVA API - [EnvelopeApi](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/esign/api/EnvelopesApi.java)